# Why is the APU controller and ECB located aft without ventilation on Boeing and Airbus aircraft?

Tags: aircraft-design, aircraft-systems, avionics, apu

On Boeing and Airbus aircraft, the APU controller and electronic control box (ECB) is located aft. Why is it located here, where no ventilation is available?

Why it is isolated from different line-replaceable units (LRUs)?

Comment: There are various inlets for APU. Google "APU inlets" with a specific aircraft type, and you get pictures (and location). APU is used a lot on ground, so you want to place where it will not interfere with ground handling. I think Centre-Of-Mass may be also relevant (on empty aircraft).

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi: can you post it as an answer? I think it's worth some upvotes 

Comment: The question is asking why the electronic *controller* for the APU is located aft; the comment by @GiacomoCatenazzi talks about why *the APU itself* is located aft.  I don't think that would be an answer to the stated question.